# Matlab - OOP variables not updating to list

Tags: matlab, oop, plot, simulation

I am trying to plot movement of dots using object oriented. I generate dots at initial position, then add their position to a vector and give them properties.There is a 1000x1000 grid as a background.

```
uav1 = uavclass([10,10,10]);
uav2 = uavclass([-10,-10,-10]);
uav3 = uavclass([20,20,20]);
uav4 = uavclass([-20,-20,-20]);
uav5 = uavclass([30,30,30]);
XY = [];
XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
    uav5.position(1),];
XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
    uav5.position(2),];

UAVs = plot(XY(:,1), XY(:,2), ...
        'Marker', '.', ...
        'Color', 'r', ...
        'LineStyle', 'none', ...
        'MarkerSize', 8);
```

When i go to plot however using

```
while uav2.charge > 25
    uav2.position(1) = uav2.position(1) + uav2.maxHorizSpeed;
    uav2.position(2) = uav2.position(2) + uav2.maxHorizSpeed;
    uav2.position(2)
    uav2.charge = uav2.charge - 1;
    pause(0.5)
    set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
end
drawnow
```

it does not plot. The value of uav2.position increases, but it does not increase in the vector XY and no movement happens.
The class is

```
classdef uavclass
    properties
        position = [0,0,0]
        charge = 100;
        destination = [0,0,0];
        maxVertClimb = 2;
        maxHorizSpeed = 5;
        sensorRange = 25;
        unloadingTime = 60;
        safeDistance = 5;
        chargingTime = 300;
        minCruiseAlt = 20;
        maxCruiseAlt = 70;
    end
    methods
        function uav = uavclass(pos)
            uav.position = pos;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not explicitly update `XY`. I would recommend to put the `uav` in a object array, so that you can directly obtain `XY` with a single call.